# Is it possible to make the Numpad 5 button work as the Numpad Down button while Num Lock is on?

Tags: autohotkey, numpad, button-remapping

I hope someone can help me out with this; I use a laptop and I like to play games a lot that are arrow key dependent. So after a while of using my laptop, I accidentally broke the <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> key. So I decided to try and find out how to make the <kbd>Numpad5</kbd> button work as the <kbd>Numpad Down</kbd> button while <kbd>Numlock</kbd> is on. I was trying to use AutoHotkey, but so far I've had no luck. Can anyone help me out with this?

So far the scripts I used that didn't work were `Numpad5::NumpadDown` or `Numpad5::Down`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: As an alternative you can try using 2 as Down Arrow (with Numlock Off), I think it is inbuilt and shouldn't need AHK. Is there any particular reason to have it working with Numlock ON.

Comment: Check whether it works outside the game. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#games

Comment: @Lamb, as far an I'm concerned numlock needs to be on to use the numpad arrow keys. And I'm trying to do this to play a game because one of my arrow keys is broken. I figured it out though. But the game doesn't seem to like the change so now it's a whole different problem. Thanks though..

Comment: @EdwinAleman Typically, numlock *on* means use the numbers while numlock *off* means use the arrows/home/pgup/end/pgdn keys. But that should not affect how AHK sees the keys.

Answer (score 4):

- Open the ahk-window by double-clicking the pictogram (right below in the taskbar).
- View menu: Key history and script info.
- Press numpad 5 while numlock is off
- Press F5 to see the VK code of numpad5.

My keyboard numpad5 is 0C, so the script is:

vk0C::NumpadDown

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone like me find this page by wanting the same thing, the answer is `NumpadClear::NumpadDown`